# Mysql query to select all data of current month between start of the month until now

Tags: mysql

I need little help with my MySQL query. I have 2 MySQL queries:

This code gave me all the data from the beginning of the current week to the end of the current week:

```
//Earnings - this week
$globalSalesThisW = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT SUM(earnings) AS globalSales91 FROM `affil` WHERE DATE(date + INTERVAL (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(date)) YEAR)
BETWEEN DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY) AND DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 6 - WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY); ");
```

and this code gave me all the data from the beginning of the current month to the end of the current month:

```
//Earnings - this month
$globalSalesThMonth = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT SUM(earnings) AS globalSalesThMonth1 FROM `affil` WHERE date between (last_day(Now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY) and last_day(Now()) ");
```

I need the first query (Earnings - this week) to give me the data from the beginning of the current week (monday) until now (today including). And second query (Earnings - this month) to give me the data from the beginning of the current month until now (today including). Could someone help me with this? I am lost :) Thanks.

Comment: Change `last_day(now())` to `now()`

Comment: Unless you've already posted earnings that are in the future, why would there be a difference between the last day of the current month and now?

Comment: It is for testing purposes, the data are manually written in the database for the whole month.

Comment: Change from last_day(now()) to now() doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please post sample data and the expected results. Make sure it's plain text so I can copy and paste into a test environment. Or create a db-fiddle.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iDUvEVUGL9p2jZKTFUN7kN/1 Here is db-fiddle.

Comment: See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iDUvEVUGL9p2jZKTFUN7kN/3 the first query returns the entire month, the second returns up to the current time.

Comment: Oh, and can you please give me an example for the other code as well? Week to current date?

Comment: It's the same thing, just use `NOW()` as the end of the `BETWEEN` range. This isn't complicated.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iDUvEVUGL9p2jZKTFUN7kN/5 Can you please check? I removed this part "DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 6 - WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY);"

Comment: It seems right. What's the problem with it? You get 3716 for the full week, and 2204 for the week until the current day.